# MAAS - PXE won't boot images

Tags: server, grub2, maas, openstack, pxe

I'm currently trying to set up a maas/openstack environment for testing purpuses, but I've got problems with deploying the nodes.

When I start the node that is connected to the private network of my Cluster controller it boots from PXE but land on "GNU GRUB version 2.02 beta2-9ubuntu1.3", not booting the Image that I downloaded under "Images" are there any logs that could help me further, it seems like there is a problem with the image being sen via pxe or my config of the standard pxe file to use

Trying to import the pxe files gives me: `sudo: maas-import-pxe-files: command not found`

Comment: Trying to import the pxe files gives me:  
sudo: maas-import-pxe-files: command not found

Comment: Seems like it has something to do with hyper-v (nodes should be running on hyper-v). VMWare PXE boots fine

Answer (score 0):

Either you're confused or I am.  My take on this is that the PXE step boots up an Ubuntu image that's pre-arranged.  You say...

> "...not booting the Image that I downloaded under 'Images'..."

...which, to me, suggests that you've got OpenStack running, that you're in the website which looks like https://someipaddress/horizon, you're in the Admin section and you've clicked the Create Image button under Images.  You then selected an ISO image or similar from somewhere and you allowed that to download.

At this point then, it wants you to "create an instance" (a.k.a. "spin up a virtual machine from this image").  Upon doing so, OpenStack then will throw the work to the scheduler which will attempt to filter the existing available nodes and find a good place for this to be placed.  If it's successful it will virtualize a server and install the image you downloaded.  I'm guessing that you're not at this step yet.

On the cluster controller--on mine at least--I often...

```
cat /etc/maas/maas.log|grep nameofnode
```

...or I might...

```
juju debug-log -n 500|grep nameofnode
```

...to see what's going on.

On the nodes themselves (other than the cluster controller), you'd want to...

```
ssh Ubuntu@nameofnode.domain
```

...and then look in the /var/log/maas folder area, especially looking for the words "cloud-init" in the filename(s).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Hyper-V and I had to patch my grubx64 file as described here: [How to deploy MAAS](http://wiki.cloudbase.it/maas)

> If you plan on deploying MaaS on Hyper-V using Generation 2 images,
>   you will need to disable secure boot in VMs and patch grubx64.efi
>   located in:
>
> ```
> wget http://wiki.cloudbase.it/_media/grubnetx64.efi.gz gunzip
> grubnetx64.efi.gz 
> cp grubnetx64.efi /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/current/grubx64.efi
> ```
>
> Follow this article to [compile GRUB with Generation 2 VM support](http://wiki.cloudbase.it/hyperv-uefi-grub)